# How can I check if else conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let say I have following if condition example how can I write this is mysql query.

```
select id, 
  if date1!='' and date1!='0000-00-00'
   then    
      date1 <='2019-03-26'

  else if date2!='' and date2!='0000-00-00'
    then 
      date2 <='2019-03-26'
 from table_name;
```

I have tried sql query as below but it didn't work. I want check if one date field is null then it needs to check with another date field

```
SELECT id, title, (case when (date1 != 'NULL') 
 THEN
      date1 ='2019-03-26' 
 ELSE
      date2 ='2019-03-26'
 END)
 as state from table_name ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate conditions using the keyword `WHERE`. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

The query logic can't be assumed from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding slightly on @MarvinKlar's answer - it appears that what you want is

```
select id
  from table_name
  WHERE (date1 NOT IN ('', '0000-00-00') AND date1 <= '2019-03-26') OR
        (date2 NOT IN ('', '0000-00-00') AND date2 <= '2019-03-26')
```

Best of luck.